# Spring boot transaction rollback doesn't fire on PostgreSQL database because of idle transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, transactions

I try to execute a transactional operation and intentionally throw an exception in order to verify if a rollback is done but the rollback isn't being executed.

The PostgreSQL database version is 12.1-1 and is Docker-based.

Here is the service that contains the `@Transactional` annotation:

```
@Service
public class MyTestService {
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDataDao documentDataDao;

    @Transactional
    public void test() {
        DocumentData data = new DocumentData();
        data.setData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        documentDataDao.create(data);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test rollback");
    }
}
```

The `create` function is using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to insert the data:

```
String statement = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s) RETURNING %s", tableName,
                String.join(",", insertingColumns), String.join(",", values),
                String.join(",", returningColumns));
return getNamedJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(statement, parameters, getRowMapper());
```

And the `test` function is called from another service:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationStartupListener {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationStartupListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyTestService testService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            testService.test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("fail to start", e);
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging I found out that if the rollback isn't executed it's because of the transaction being `IDLE`.

Here is the `rollback` function from `PgConnection` and `executeTransactionCommand` isn't being executed:

```
public void rollback() throws SQLException {
    checkClosed();

    if (autoCommit) {
      throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("Cannot rollback when autoCommit is enabled."),
          PSQLState.NO_ACTIVE_SQL_TRANSACTION);
    }

    if (queryExecutor.getTransactionState() != TransactionState.IDLE) {
      executeTransactionCommand(rollbackQuery);
    }
  }
```

Any hint on why the transaction is being marked as idle and stops the rollback method to be executed would be appreciated.

#### Edit (1)

As @M. Deinum mentioned, there is no guarantee that a transactional proxy has been created when using `@PostConstruct`. That's why I tested with an `ApplicationRunner`:

```
@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private MyTestService testService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
           testService.test();
    }
}
```

But this didn't work either.

I also tried to run the `test` method a few moments after the application has been started by using a `RestController` and sending an HTTP request to it but still, the same issue.

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private MyTestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> test() {
        testService.test();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

#### Edit (2)

I upgraded the PostgreSQL JDBC version from 42.2.2 to 42.2.18 (latest as of now) but the connection is still IDLE when trying to rollback.

#### Edit (3)

I reproduced the issue in a git repository: https://github.com/Martin-Hogge/spring-boot-postgresql-transactional-example/tree/master.

Comment: did you try this rollbackFor => @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)

Comment: Yes and I get the same result -> no rollback.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a transactional proxy has already been created when using `@PostConstruct`. You should use a proper listener or use an `ApplicationRunner` which executes after everything has started has been fully initialized.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Unfortunately this wasn't the issue - I edited the post with the details.

Comment: And `idle` transaction is not a problem and does not indicate there is a n open transaction. `idle in transaction` would indicate an open transaction.

Comment: But the fact that the transaction is idle prevent the rollback from being executed. As you can see in the `PgConnection`: `if (this.queryExecutor.getTransactionState() != TransactionState.IDLE) { executeTransactionCommand(rollbackQuery); }`. My transaction shouldn't be `idle` at this moment, am I right ?

Comment: Did you provide a TransactionManager bean in your app?

Comment: I did not configure anything but as far as I understand a `DataSourceTransactionManager` is automatically created. What I do is creating a `HikariDataSource`. I put a breakpoint inside the method `doRollback` of `DataSourceTransactionManager` and it pass through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I examined the architecture that you want to use multiple schemas (data sources, jdbc templates) in a single application. `@Transactional` only manages application's default data source that is named `HikariPool-1`. When you call the rest method, new hikari pool will be created that is named `HikariPool-2`. Your operations are on `HikariPool-2`, but `@Transactional` manages only `HikariPool-1`.

`@Transactional`'s transaction manager argument can not be changed dynamically. So, you can define a new custom annotation that manages your transactions. Or you can use `TransactionTemplate` instead of annotations.

I created a simple custom transaction management aspect. It is working with defined dao's data source and transaction lifecycle.

### Test Service

```java
@Service
public class MyTestService {
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDataDao documentDataDao;

    @CustomTransactional(DocumentDataDao.class)
    public void test() {
        DocumentData data = new DocumentData();
        data.setData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        documentDataDao.create(data);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test rollback");
    }
}
```

### Custom Transactional

```java
package com.example.transactional;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface CustomTransactional {
    Class<? extends BaseDao<?>> value();
}
```

### Custom Transactional Aspect

```java
package com.example.transactional;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomTransactionalAspect implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private Map<Class<? extends BaseDao<?>>, BaseDao<?>> classMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Around("@annotation(customTransactional)")
    public Object customTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CustomTransactional customTransactional) throws Throwable {
        BaseDao<?> baseDao = getBaseDao(customTransactional.value());

        // custom transaction management
        return baseDao.getConnectionHandler().getTransactionTemplate().execute(status -> {
            try {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Search {@link BaseDao} class on spring beans
     *
     * @param clazz Target dao class type
     * @return Spring bean object
     */
    private BaseDao<?> getBaseDao(Class<? extends BaseDao<?>> clazz) {
        return classMap.computeIfAbsent(clazz, c -> applicationContext.getBean(c));
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

### Connection Handler

I added `transactionTemplate` for transaction operations

```java
public class ConnectionHandler {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
    private String schema;

    public ConnectionHandler(DataSource dataSource, String schema) {
        this.namedJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.schema = schema;

        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource));
    }

    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedJdbcTemplate() {
        return namedJdbcTemplate;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public TransactionTemplate getTransactionTemplate() {
        return transactionTemplate;
    }
}
```

### BaseDao

Change modifier of `getConnectionHandler` to `public`.

```java
    public ConnectionHandler getConnectionHandler() {
        return getDataSource().getConnection(getSchemaName());
    }
```

### pom.xml

You can remove `postgresql.version`, `spring-jdbc.version` and `HikariCP.version`. Problem is not related with versions. Add `spring-boot-starter-aop` dependency for aspect operations.

```xml
<dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @MHogge I developed custom JPA implementation like yours (instead of hibernate). I hope, you will be successful.